# Move-Action in an occupied square-Move?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

Last evening my sorceress did the following: She's standing behind the barbarian in a hallway, and the enemies are lined up in the hallway in front of the barbarian. She moves into the barbarian's square (to avoid hitting him with her lightning bolt), fires her lightning bolt down the hallway, then she retreats to her original square. Is this allowed?

Note that:

- She doesn't end her turn in an occupied square.
- She would have suffered and attack of opportunity (however, her lightning bolt killed the enemies so she didn't)